# How to get the output of time command in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, time, output, io-redirection

This command work perfectly in my shell and I want to write it inside a bash script but it doesn't work anymore :

```
make -s clean > /dev/null; { time make -j -s gallery > /dev/null; } 2>&1 | grep real | sed 's/^.*m//;s/.$/ /' > time_make
```

The problem is the outpout of time.

In the shell this commande :

```
make -s clean > /dev/null; { time make -j 1 -s gallery > /dev/null; } 2>&1 | grep m > time_make
```

has for result :

```
real   0m2.127s
user   0m3.375s
sys    0m0.532s
```

That's good.

But in the script (#! /bin/sh):

The same command has for result :

```
3.36user 0.51system 0:02.08elapsed 186%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata49100maxresident)k
0inputs+2384outputs (0major+114980minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

How to get the value of "real" in the bash script?

I really don't understand why it's not the same output for the "time" command. Could anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running `/usr/bin/time` explicitly.

Comment: ah.... it gives me the one I don't want.   thank you,  so the other one should be....   umh i tried the other given by "whereis time" but I didn't find a good one

Comment: Use `which time` to find out what is being used.  It might be part of the shell, and not a command at all.

Comment: It gives me the one you said,

Comment: If you read the man-page for Bash you'll find that it provides its own time.  There is only one option `time -p` for POSIX-style output.  Maybe that's what you're after?

Comment: it works, time -p thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the time a command takes in bash, you can get a lot more control by doing something like this (assumes you're on a system with GNU time installed):

```
START=$(date +%s.%N)
# command you want to time goes here
END=$(date +%s.%N)
printf -v DELTA "%g" $(bc <<<"$END - $START")
echo "Command took ${DELTA} seconds"
```

You can actually format the output into hours, minutes, seconds etc.